# Cannot pin ADT in taksbar in windows 7

Tags: android, adt, android-ide

I cant pin ADT into the taskbar in windows 7. The icon also turns to eclipse and when the IDE opens up it turns into like this.

[image]

When i right click on the icon it only shows the close option. Anyway to resolve this problem?

Im using the 64bit version by the way.

Comment: which adt u hv downloded 64bit??

Comment: +1 Yup I have noticed this icon change many times in my 64 bit machine.

Comment: @adcom version 23.0.0

Comment: i mean there is adt for 64 and 32 bit differently, can u open any eclipse with adding adt there

Comment: I have a 32bit version of ADT and it work's fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed it. What I did was

Open the eclipse.ini which can be found at the root folder of your eclipse folder and place this line of code at the very top. Make sure you place it at the very top to avoid errors.

> > -vm
> >     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin (This will depend where you install your JRE)

save your changes and close your IDE if it's open. When you reopen it. The broken icon turns to eclipse icon. Right the icon and select ***pin this program to taskbar*** and you're done.